# How to get div content that was echoed by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to get a value inside a div content. After a button click and doing stuff on the server side, my PHP function does:

```
echo "0";
```

or

```
echo "1";
```

depending on what my function does. So let's say if it's `0`, the AJAX response will be `$("div#divResult").html(data);` where I put the 0 in the div `divResult`.

What I am trying to do now is I want to execute a js function to read whether it's `0` or `1` in `divResult`.

This is how I execute it:

```
<div id="divResult"><script>getDivResult();</script></div>
```

And my js function:

```
function getDivResult()
{
    var result = $("div#divResult").text();

    if(result === "0")
    {
        alert("Badge Number already exists, please check again.");
    }
    else if(result === "1")
    {
        alert("Your details have been entered!")
        ADD_USER_POPUP.close;
    }
}
```

Somehow the `getDivResult` function is not executing. The 0 and 1 does display on in the div though. Any help on this? I've tried `.html` too by the way.

EDIT:

Here's the AJAX that I use for the button click and return the response from PHP which is either 1 or 0:

```
$.post(page, {
    name : name,
    badge_number : badge_number,
    category : category,
    priviledge : priviledge,
    action : "insert"
    }, function(data) {
    $("div#divResult").html(data);
    });
```

2nd EDIT:

```
    function insertRow($name, $badge_number, $priviledge, $category)
    {
    $table_info = "TBL_USER_LOGIN";
    $query_string = "select badge_number from $table_info where badge_number = $badge_number";
    $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
    $checkBadge = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($checkBadge>0)
    {
        //echo "Badge Number $badge_number already exists. Please check again.";
        echo "0";
    }
    else
    {
        $query_string = "insert into $table_info(name, badge_number, priviledge, category) values('$name', '$badge_number', '$priviledge', '$category')";
        $result = @mysql_query($query_string) or die (mysql_error());
        //echo "Your details have been entered! Please click on 'View Users' to display all users.";
        echo "1";
    }

?>

    <?php

    $action = rtrim($_REQUEST['action']);

    if($action=="delete")
    {
        $id  = rtrim($_REQUEST['id']);
        $order = $_REQUEST['order'];

        echo deleteRow($id);
        echo selectAll($order);
    }
    elseif($action=="insert")
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $badge_number = $_REQUEST['badge_number'];
        $priviledge = $_REQUEST['priviledge'];
        $category = $_REQUEST['category'];

        echo insertRow($name, $badge_number, $priviledge, $category);
    }
    elseif($action=="update")
    {
        $order = $_REQUEST['order'];

        echo selectAll($order);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Try using the correct comparison operator in your if statements. `===` will evaluate TRUE or FALSE, while `==` will compare the integer or string.

Comment: They way you're currently executing the function is wrong; by the time that function runs the contents will always be `"getDivResult();"`.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I do get a `0` or `1` in the div. It's just that the alerts don't pop up.

Comment: This seems like a debugging exercise, then.

Comment: @Ja͢ck No, I can choose to just echo the direct response instead of a `0` or `1` but if I do, `window.close` doesn't work so that's why I asked the question as if it is possible to read the div based on what PHP has echoed.

Comment: What `window.close()` are you talking about? If you're not sharing enough code you will not get a lot of meaningful answers, if any.

Comment: What I was referring from `window.close` was to `ADD_USER_POPUP.close` in my code. I resolved it anyway, will ticked the answer I followed in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to append the return data to the page at all. Why don't you run your function immediately after the AJAX request completes, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
    if(data === "0") {
      alert("Badge Number already exists, please check again.");
    }
    else if(data === "1") {
      alert("Your details have been entered!")
      ADD_USER_POPUP.close();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, the alerts don't pop up.

Comment: console.log(data); It's probably not just a string.

Comment: Where do I do console.log(data)? In the javascript? Which part?

Comment: Just add console.log(data); right above "if(data === '0') {"

Comment: Did that, I get `console is undefined`?

Comment: Which browser & version are you using?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support console. IE8 is really old and bad. I'd suggest using basically any other browser.

Comment: Used firefox, it outputs the value that I want, `1` or `0`.

Comment: Are they strings or integers? 1 isn't equal to "1".

Comment: Ahhh thank you for that. It does alert now but my main thing I want to do is close the window after success. I tried `window.close()` but the window doesn't close either. Will mark your ans as the right one once I get this working.

Comment: I followed your way, but I tweaked it a bit where by I just put everything into the response followed by a `window.close()` when `data==1`. Thanks for giving me a rough idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

place getDivResult() to onclick in which button you click like

> < button onclick="getDivResult()">Click me< /button>"

i think it will be work with you.

Comment: No, I don't want the user to click on it. It's supposed to be hidden.

Comment: Your code doesnt work, because when your html start loading your script execute and var result in your script is nothing . so you should do something else if you want to run this code. i dont really understand what you want to do. sr if this not help you.

Comment: Basically I want to alert based on whether PHP has echoed `0` or `1`. My idea was to send this response to a div in my HTML. Then I would execute another javascript function to read whether it is `0` or `1` and alert the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.html(data)` all the existing elements wipedoff and replaced by new content:

```
$("div#divResult").html(data);
```

I guess you should do this:

```
$("div#divResult").html(data);
getDivResult(); // call after it. and put the function globally.
```

Comment: Tried as you suggested, this doesn't work. Same thing, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

enclose the echo with a div then trying getting the value by the id.

or

try echoing via json enconde 
[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
then fetch the value by using AJAX

Comment: I don't think I need to to json_encode just to fetch a digit value.

Comment: can you post your full code for the php page? or just the function

Answer (score 0):

i think, this script `<script>getDivResult();</script>` was replaced the content of `#divResult` by ajax code  `$("div#divResult").html(data);`. Instead of that, place the script inside head section rather than inside `#divResult` to execute that.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ajax? How do you do it?

It looks like you're using jQuery. Try reading the documentation
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

You can try something like this:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  if(data === "0")
  {
      alert("Badge Number already exists, please check again.");
  }
  else if(data  === "1")
  {
      alert("Your details have been entered!")
      ADD_USER_POPUP.close;
  }
});
```

data should be your 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Run your function

```
getDivResult();
```

after

```
$("div#divResult").html(data);
```

in `ajax`